# Suppression list on Amazon SES not blocking messages with multiple recipients

Tags: amazon-ses

I use an account-level [suppression list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-email-suppression-list.html) on Amazon SES. I have noticed that if I send an email message to an email address which is in the suppression list, for example, *name1@domain.com*, the message is not blocked by the suppression list if the "to" field of the email message has more than one recipient email address. Something like this:

`To: name1@domain.com, name2@anotherdomain.com`

The email *name1@domain.com* is in the suppression list and *name2@anotherdomain.com* is not.

In this case, the email is delivered to both email addresses, even though *name1@domain.com* is in the suppression list. The suppression list only blocks my messages when the email is sent to a single email recipient.

It looks like the suppression list only blocks messages sent to a single email address. I could not find any documentation about this, but my tests show this. Has anyone noticed this also? Am I missing something or is this the expected behavior?

I am sure that the email address *name1@domain.com* is in the suppression list, I have checked it via web console and via `aws sesv2 list-suppressed-destinations`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check it. First of all, you have checked that only in case of two email addresses - lets name them A and B, if one of them is on suppression list and another one not, the email is sent.

Check another version - what if both A and B addresses are on suppression list - is the mail still sent? I would argue that it is not, even though it might be accepted through SES, it might not be sent.

Coming back to your part - when you send an email and add to the TO headers - it is one mail that is being delivered to multiple people - so in order to be consistent, SES is not modifying email headers, however it sends it - and one of the recipients is one on the suppression list and another one not, so both of them receive it as only one mail is being sent. If I were you, I would check adding the same addresses to the BCC - as for this part, the mail is being copied and in your case, there would be two mails sent (one with BCC to A and another one to B). I could assume that this part could be handled and blocked by SES.